# How to center text inside button?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button

Hi i have one little problem with my [site](http://touchdowner.cz/digitalni-produkty/). I have one button into to header, but text inside looks misaligned. How to make text to be a little UP into button? Currently is a little down.

This is CSS class for that button:

```
header .popup_link {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 30px !important;
}
```

What to do to make text properly alligned inside button?

Comment: Since you said **"a little UP"**, you mean center it vertically?

Comment: Looking at the site, it looks like @Swellar

Comment: If you are using an Height attribute, something that can helps it's `line-height`attribute with the same px size, in this case, 20px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line height too:

```
header .popup_link{
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have line-height 24px and height of `<a>` 20px - just do something with one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove height :

```
header .popup_link {
  padding: 3px 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: Not help me, because i want to make button a more fit.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your website, and you have a problem with vertical center.
using flex is the simplest way to solve this.

Add this css on your button:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

You can set your preferred height with this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your button using this css rules:

```
.little-head a.blue-btn span{
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
```

**Notice**: I added a class `.blue-btn` to your button. You are free to rename it according to your needs.

This css rules will vertically align the inner span relatively to its parent which is the blue button in this case.
Here is the result [image]

Comment: Your code fixed text inside button, but cart box now looks strange. See https://i.imgur.com/WTPBa4H.png?1

Comment: oo, I know the reason. It is because it has the same structure like the button. Then you have to assign some class or id to the button itself. I am gonna suggest you a solution in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to `<span>` tag and Add This Style for that `id`:

```
<style>

#btn_Přihlásit{
text-align: center; 
display: flex;
margin-top: -2px;

</style>

<span id="btn_Přihlásit">Přihlásit se</span>
```

**Output:**

[image]